# Mapping custom types Fortran-to-Java (with JNA)

Tags: java, java-native-interface, fortran, jna

I have to write an interface of of Fortran subroutine to be called from Java. Some arguments in the Fortran subroutine are derived types (custom types / struct). Is it possible to map those with JNA? So far I cannot so how this could work. What about JNI?

e.g. a subroutine like this:

```
subroutine mysub(arg)
implicit none
type mytype
   integer:: i
   real*8 :: a(3)
end type mytype

type(mytype) arg

! do stuff...

end subroutine mysub
```

Comment: Can you give some example of the sort of derived types/subroutines you care about?  Some aspects make the whole thing a lot more challenging.  [And you could look at the [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding] for using a C interoperable interface.]

Comment: @francescalus I added an example of what I mean

Comment: I hope your example actually has the type definition _outside_ (but accessible in) the subroutine...

Comment: Are changes to the Fortran code agreeable?

Comment: the type definition is in a include-file and is therefore also visible from the outside. Changes are agreeable, but I want to avoid to pass every single argument of the struct/type separately using an additional fortran-wrapper (this would blow up the number of arguments quite a bit)

Comment: As a side note (it doesn't immediately help your case), your Fortran code sounds broken.  If you have a file which has literal text with the `type...end type` definition which is `include`d by the subroutine and by another program unit which calls that subroutine then the two occurrences of that type definition actually define two _different_ types which are not compatible.  Where this is interesting is that if you change the literal text to have the type with the `bind` attribute they then define the same type.  This `bind` attribute is useful in the C interoperability.

Comment: Agreed, you cannot legally just include the type definition. You must create the type at one place and use it using modules. The standard does not allow any other way except for the `bind(C)` types. Not sure about `sequence` types, but I think they need the module.

Comment: `sequence` and bind(c) are the same in this respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JNA supports aggregate types (`struct` in C) both by reference and by value.  The default convention for arguments is by value, e.g.

```
public interface MyLibrary extends Library {
    MyLibrary INSTANCE = (MyLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("mylib", MyLibrary.class);

    class MyStruct extends Structure {
        public static class ByValue extends MyStruct implements Structure.ByValue {}
        public int i;
        public double a[3];
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("i", "a");
        }
    }

    void mysub(MyStruct.ByValue arg);
}
```

Comment: thanks, thats great... I see that there are many examples here :http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/index.html?example=3 I was too much focused on interfacing with Fortran

Comment: But I think you have to implement `getFieldOrder()` in the above code, otherwise I get an compilation error (jna 4.2)

Comment: Why is `class ByValue extends MyStruct implements Structure.ByValue {}` needed, what if this is omitted?

Comment: If a Structure is a function parameter, the default value passed is the address (pointer).  If a Structure is a member of another struct, the default value is the Structure itself.  The ByValue and ByReference tags are there in case you want the behavior that is _not_ the default.  It's not required, but it makes things easier for anyone else who uses your code.